# Where was this picture of Oriental boats near European-looking buildings taken?

Tags: identify-this, riverboats

I saw this in a 1973 Nikon School of Photography ad with no caption.

[image: The boats seem Oriental, but the buildings seem European.]

Does anyone know where this is? The boats seem Oriental, but the buildings seem European.

Comment: The buildings don't look very European to me.

Comment: Where did this image come from?

Comment: 1973 Nikon School of Photography ad. No caption.

Comment: I am almost positive that this is in Osaka, Japan.. Just can't find a proof yet. Building, boats, the river, and the mountain all suggests so.

Comment: @NeanDerThal The church spires don't look very Japanese to me?

Comment: @lambshaanxy seems like a temple to me

Comment: I was thinking Fenghuang, but the spire isn't there and the mountains would be much closer. I don't think it's Fenghuang.

Comment: @NeanDerThal Japanese temples don't have spires/bell towers like that.

Comment: @lambshaanxy I just figured out that you are jpatokal, I am sure you know Japan way better than I do.

Answer (score 18):

[Srinagar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Srinagar), Kashmir - old city with river Jhelum. The "temple" is in fact the [Khanqah-e-Moula Mosque](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khanqah-e-Moula), one of the oldest mosques in Kashmir.

Here's another old photography, showing a similar view:

[image]
(Source: https://www.spiked-online.com/2019/08/13/kashmir-a-tale-of-two-mothers )

A modern stock photo from that place:

[image]

Google has a similar but modern view:

[image]

And another one, from the opposite direction:

[image]

Comment: if anyone knows when that bridge was built, it could confirm nicely

Comment: @KateGregory: The predecessor of that bridge (i assume it's the Fateh Kadal bridge) seems to be quite old, dating back to the 18th century (or maybe  the 15th century). According the this page: https://kashmirasitis.com/bridges-historical-srinagar , Fateh Kadal was the oldes bridge ot Srinagar's seven main bridges, but it doesn't give a year. Other bridges date back to 1774 (Amira kadal), 1551 (Haba Kadal) and 1415 (Ail Kadal), so anyway i think the old Fateh Kadal was built before photography was invented ;-)

Comment: Another nice pic from Flickr, dated 1944: https://flic.kr/p/as13tm